# Find should return only successful search results: Mac OS

Tags: macos, unix, find

I have been using Mac OS X (Mavericks). I am using *find* command to search file in the terminal.

Presently, it returns also unsuccessful search results, saying "No such file or directory". How can I get rid of that (no 'grep'-like command please) and get my screen display only the successful hits?

I didn't encounter this when I used Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
your_find_command 2>/dev/null
```

This will redirect the errors to `/dev/null` . So, you will not see the errors in terminal.

Comment: Can we re-define *find* command in my .bash_profile so that I don't need to type *2>/dev/null* every time?

Comment: @hbaromega, You can redefine your find command in `.bash_profile` like the above ( `find ... 2>/dev/null` ).

Comment: But won't the pattern name appear as a variable or argument? E.g. can

`find . -iname <pattern>* 2>/dev/null` 

be replaced as 

`newfind . -iname <pattern>* `

where 

`alias newfind = find 2>/dev/null` 

I think, it will be incorrect.